# Install windows 7 onto another hdd

Tags: partitioning, windows

This is my current hdd set up

sd0 -- ext4 storage drive

sd1 -- ext4 storage drive

sd2 -- ext4 boot drive

sd3 -- NTSF Drive that I want to boot windows 7

whenever I put in my cd and decide to install onto sd3 it says unable to create a new system partition. Even when it lets me delete, create, and format the drive.

Here is all of the drives:

[image]

Comment: go to : http://superuser.com/questions/520801/only-three-primary-partitions

Comment: @Terminal why? op try to install windows on a preinstalled Ubuntu pc.

Comment: Upload the gparted screenshot.

Comment: http://imgur.com/j0j2dMY this is the drive I want to install windows onto.

Comment: post the gparted screenshot of your 1st hdd.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/WxZkQ#0 Here is all of the drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe both Ubuntu and Windows require GUID formated partition tables (GPT) on drives larger than 2TB. Most likely your computer is running BIOS not UEFI which isn't a problem except that Windows requires UEFI to use GPT. The drive you want to install Windows on is under 2TB and therefore can be formated in MBR, but because it's not the first boot drive windows can't install. Windows installs it' bootloader to the mbr of the first boot drive, but the first boot drive is Ubuntu, and so it's being detected as GPT which cannot have an MBR entry added. I would sugggest disconnceting all your hard drives except Windows, install windows then reconnect them. This will allow you to boot Ubuntu by default, but if you enter your bios at boot up you should be able to tell it to boot the windows hard drive instead. Please note that some computers don't allow selecting which hard drive to boot from in the bios quickboot list, if this is the case for you then you'll be unable too boot WIndows because Ubuntu will boot first, so you'll need to add an entry to the grub bootloader for Windows.